# Replaces command for label in helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I often see the following snippet in the helm charts:

```
  labels:
    app: {{ template "app.name" . }}
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
```

Why is the replacement necessary? Are `+` signs bad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per this (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#syntax-and-character-set) documentation, labels cannot have plus(+) character in its value.

```
The name segment is required and must be 63 characters or less, beginning and ending with an alphanumeric character ([a-z0-9A-Z]) with dashes (-), underscores (_), dots (.), and alphanumerics between.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Replace - script and chart function**
`Replace()` returns a string after replacing all occurrences of a given substring within the input string with another substring. The function is non-recursive and works from left to right.

**Syntax:**

Replace(text, from_str, to_str)
Return data type: string

Valid label values in pod configuration file must be 63 characters or less and must be empty or begin and end with an alphanumeric character `([a-z0-9A-Z])` with dashes `(-)`, underscores `(_)`, dots `(.)`, and alphanumerics between.

`replace "+" "_"` replaces plus characters with underscores. And that is how we avoid failures.

More information you can find here: [replace-chart](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2019/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/StringFunctions/Replace.htm), [syntax-pod-label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#syntax-and-character-set).